# How to implement a themed monochrome icon for Material You

Tags: android, android-studio, material-ui, material-components-android

How would I implement a monochrome icon like other google apps so that it matches the dynamic colours picked by Material You?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Open your app icon and add the monochrome android:drawable attribute to the `<adaptive-icon>` element. For example, in res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml:

```
<adaptive-icon >
    <background android:drawable="..." />
    <foreground android:drawable="..." />
    <monochrome android:drawable="@drawable/mymonochromeicon" />
</adaptive-icon>
```

If your try this and it does not work then you need to remove the `android:roundIcon` element from your `AndroidManifest.xml`, or, alternatively, also add the `<monochrome android:drawable="@drawable/mymonochromeicon"/>` tag to your round icon.

Android Studio might give a warning saying `Element monochrome is not allowed here` however we can ignore this.

Comment: Will it work in Android 12, targeting SDK version 31? No.

Comment: Because Google opened it up for other developers from Android 13